# Изменение размера картинки при загрузке на php (не могу настроить корректно)

Tags: php, fileupload, загрузка, upload

Добрый день! Помогите сделать одну штуку! Есть уменьшение размера картинки , точнее исходный размер  $final_width_of_image = 1600;

Но! При загрузке например 800х800пкс он картинки растягивает до указанных 1600пкс.

Как сделать сто бы картинки больше 1600пкс резались , а меньшего разрешения не менялись (не растягивались до 1600пкс)

Заранее спасибо :)

```
<?php

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_photo']['tmp_name']))
{                                      
    if ( ($_FILES['upload_photo']['type'] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES['upload_photo']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['upload_photo']['type'] == 'image/png') && $_FILES['upload_photo']['size'] <= 2024000 ) 
    {       

        $new_name = date("d-m-Y-h-i-s",strtotime("+0 hour"));       

        $upload_photo = $new_name.'-'.$_FILES['upload_photo']['name'];
        //copy($_FILES['upload_photo']['tmp_name'],"../newsimg/".$upload_photo);

$file_name = $_FILES['upload_photo']['name']; 


$path =    '../pro/';

if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/',$new_name.'-'.$_FILES['upload_photo']['name']))//проверка формата
                             {   


                                           $filename    = $new_name.'-'.$_FILES['upload_photo']['name'];
                                           $source    = $_FILES['upload_photo']['tmp_name'];        
                                           $target    = $path . $filename;
                                           move_uploaded_file($source, $target); 


 $final_width_of_image = 1600;


    if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](jpeg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](JPG)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](JPEG)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($path . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](GIF)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($path . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($path . $filename);
    } 

    $ox = imagesx($im);
    $oy = imagesy($im);

    $nx = $final_width_of_image;
    $ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));


  $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

  imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);    


    imagejpeg($nm, $path . $filename);

}



        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.document.getElementById(\"imageId\").innerHTML = '<img src=\"../pro/{$upload_photo}\" alt=\"\" style=\"max-width:350px;\">'; parent.document.getElementById(\"image_upload_status\").innerHTML = '<p class=\"image_success\"><br><b>Изображение <span class=\"ni\">{$upload_photo}</span> успешно загружено: &nbsp;  <span class=\"imgsc\" style=\"color:blue;cursor:pointer;\">в галерею</span></b></p>';</script>";
    }
    else if (($_FILES['upload_photo']['type'] != 'image/gif' && $_FILES['upload_photo']['type'] != 'image/jpeg' && $_FILES['upload_photo']['type'] != 'image/png'))
    {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.document.getElementById(\"image_upload_status\").innerHTML = '<p class=\"image_error\">Недопустимый тип файла</p>';</script>";
    }
    else if ($_FILES['upload_photo']['size'] > 2024000)
    {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.document.getElementById(\"image_upload_status\").innerHTML = '<p class=\"image_error\">Недопустимый размер файла</p>';</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.document.getElementById(\"image_upload_status\").innerHTML = '<p class=\"image_error\">Произошла ошибка при загрузке файла</p>';</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто вроверяйте ширину, если больше 1600, тогда режьте, если нет - просто пропускайте этот блок:

```
$ox = imagesx($im); // тут ширина картинки
$oy = imagesy($im); // тут высота картинки

if ($ox > 1600) {
   $nx = $final_width_of_image;
    $ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));


    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

    imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);    


    imagejpeg($nm, $path . $filename); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)